# AMPL - Express summation with max function

Tags: ampl, gurobi

I need to declare this image in my .mod as "subject to" but i don't know how to do it. Can someone explain it to me? My main problem is max{0,t-4}.

[image: here]

I tried:

```
    set ANY_INICI:=1..10;
    subject to constr{t in 1 .. 10}:
        sum {j in max(0,t-4)+1 .. ANY_INICI, i in t-j+1 .. 4} decisio[i,j]>=restriccio[t];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form is:

t iterates ANY_INICI and 1..10 is equal to ANY_INICI param

```
subject to constr{t in ANY_INICI }:
        sum {j in max(0,t-4)+1..t, i in t-j+1..4} decisio[i,j] >= restriccio[t];
```